# List all entries except 'hidden'

Tags: templating

So I hope I am explaining this correctly.

I have some entries with a tag called 'hidden'. In my blog layout I want to exclude those entries.

I have the following:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.name('hidden') %}
{% set hiddenentry = craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo(tag).find() %}
{% set allentry = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(5).find() %}
{% set unhidden = allentry|without(hiddenentry) %}

{% for entry in unhidden %}
    <div class="content">
        <article>
            <h2><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="date">Posted on {{ entry.postDate.format('F d, Y') }}</p>
            {{ entry.body.getPage(1) }}
            {# {{ entry.summary }} #}
            <button><a href="{{ entry.url }}">Continue reading</a></button>
        </article>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really the answer you are looking for, but it might be easier to change the tag `hidden` to a checkbox or lightswitch field and add a condition to the `for..in` loop, as explained in the [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition), which may do what you need and keep the query count lower.

```
{% for entry in allEntries if not entry.hidden %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```